# Search Icon inside a Editable JComboBox / JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have an **`Editable JComboBox`** **search field** in one of my Java swing application. I wanted to save space of the search box header and put in search icon **inside the `editable jcombobox`** to depict it as a search field. Which should look quite similar to a Facebook search field.
So, my question is that, Is there any way to achieve such a thing in `Java`? As a beginner my idea is void about this. Any suggestion / help would positively work for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom Border on the editor of the combo box which is a text field:

```
ComboBoxEditor editor = comboBox.getEditor();
JTextField textField = (JTextField)editor.getEditorComponent();
Border outer = textField.getBorder();
Border search = new MatteBorder(0, 16, 0, 0, new ImageIcon("search.gif"));
textField.setBorder( new CompoundBorder(outer, search) );
```

The MatteBorder will tile the image in the Border, so you need to make sure the image is the size of the text field, or you create a custom Border that only paints the image once.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information.

Comment: Works fine, but `comboBox` in the first line is an unknown component. But no worries I added these lines `JComboBox<String> jcbx = new JComboBox<>();`   
        `JTextField editorComponent = (JTextField) jcbx.getEditor().getEditorComponent();`
        
           `jcbx.setEditable(true);`

Comment: @mustangDC, `works fine` - don't forget to "accept" this answer (and all your others) so people know the problem has been solved. The point of the posted code was to show you how to display the icon, not create a combo box.

Comment: yA .. aCCEPTED AND vOTED